# how to change the username in git?

Tags: git, github, ssh, gitlab

I know its a common question, but even after apply various solutions I'm still not able to change the username. every time when i try to push my changes on git, i'm getting below error.

`PS C:\storage\class\11-1\Angular> git push origin DevBW-AngularAws
remote: Permission to varun9797/BetterWorldUI.git denied to test9777.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/varun9777/BetterWorldUI.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403`

I tried below command as well.

`git config credential.username "varun9777"`

But still getting the same error at the time of push only.

I want to change the username `abc-xyz` to `varun9777`

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: go to the repository page on Github and get the new URL. Then use

`git remote set-url origin https://new url with username replaced`
to update the URL with your new username.

Comment: Do this in your case `git remote set-url origin https://github.com/varun9797/BetterWorldUI.git/`

Comment: still getting the same error.

Answer (score 2):

```
git remote set-url origin https://varun9797:yourPassword@github.com/varun9797/BetterWorldUI.git
```

We can set repository url that contains git credentials.

Comment: Here, github password will be stored in plaintext in your .git directory, which is obviously undesirable.

Comment: Yes, but, that is no problem, I think, `git config user.password ...` also stored git password in .git directory

Answer (score 1):

**Try these in a series**

```
git remote set-url origin https://varun9797:yourPassword@github.com/varun9797/BetterWorldUI.git
git config --global user.email "verma9797@gmail.com"
git config --global user.name "varun verma"
git config --global credential.username "varun9797"
```

go to your **.git** folder, then open **config** file. In the file paste your user info:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/varun9797/BetterWorldUI.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[user]
    name = varun-verma
    email = verma9797@gmail.com
```

Comment: As per you sugestion i tried. but still getting the same error.<br> `PS C:\storage\class\11-1\Angular> git config user.email "verma9797@gmail.com"
<br> C:\storage\class\11-1\Angular> git config user.name "varun verma"<br> C:\storage\class\11-1\Angular> git config credential.username "varun9797"
<br> C:\storage\class\11-1\Angular> git push origin DevBW-AngularAws
remote: Permission to varun9797/BetterWorldUI.git denied to shivam-perpetualny.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/varun9797/BetterWorldUI.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403`

Answer (score 0):

Try user.name instead.

For detailed description follow the link:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/configure-your-dvcs-username-for-commits-950301867.html

Comment: You could try checking the version. They say version 1.7.10  is more stable and comfortable. Check if you are pushing to older one. The second suggestion is Instead of using HTTPS URL, you can use SSH. Link-https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there is not a *the* user name.  There are *many* user names.

There is a `user.name` you can set in your Git configuration.  This sets the name put into *new* commits that you make.  It generally has no other function, though any program can query it at any time and make any use of it that this other program (whatever it is) wants.

There is a user-name embedded in some URLs:

```
git push ssh://joe@example.com/path/to/repo.git
```

embeds the user name `joe` into the SSH URL, and:

```
git fetch https://user:password@host.example.com/path/to/repo.git
```

embeds both the user name `user` and his password (not generally wise).

Your own suggestion of `credential.username` appears not to be used by anything, though since anyone can write any program at any time that uses any string for any purpose, perhaps someone has done so—but a Google search for `credential.username` turns up mostly pages like https://sysadminguides.org/2017/05/02/how-to-pass-credentials-in-powershell/ that are not about Git at all.

The [Pro Git book suggests](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage) that on Windows, you may wish to install Git Credential Manager for Windows.

In any case, once you have installed some credential helper, or chosen to use one of those built in to Git itself, you select *which* credential helper to use via `git config --global credential.helper helper`.  It's not at all clear from your question which credential helper you are using *now;* but whichever one you are using, *that* determines what setting you need to change.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your username in the remote connection string:

```
$ git remote -v
https://github.com/varun9797/BetterWorldUI.git/

$ git remote remove origin

$ git remote add origin https://username@github.com/varun9797/BetterWorldUI.git/
```

Now when you try a push / pull it should prompt you for a password.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
git remote set-url origin https://username@github.com/user/BetterWorldUI.git
```

where `username` should be `varun9797`